Tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology - Pushout of Fundamental Groupoids
The following theorem appears in Tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology.

$\textbf{(2.61) Theorem} \,\,\text{(R. Brown)}$ Let $X_0$ and $X_1$ be subspaces of $X$ such that the interiors cover $X$. Let $i_\nu: X_{01} \to X_\nu$ and $j_\nu: X_\nu \to X$ be the inclusions. Then
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Pi(X_{01}) @>\large \Pi(i_0)>> \Pi(X_{0})\\
@V \large \Pi(i_1) V V @VV \large \Pi(j_0) V\\
\Pi(X_{1}) @>>\large \Pi(j_1)> \Pi(X)
\end{CD}
is a pushout in the category of groupoids.

Proof: Let $h_\nu: \Pi(X_\nu) \to \Lambda$ be functors into a groupoid such that $h_1 \Pi(i_1) = h_0 \Pi(i_0)$. We have to show: There exists a unique functor $\lambda: \Pi(X) \to \Lambda$ such that $h_1 = \lambda \Pi(j_1)$ and $h_0 = \lambda \Pi(j_0)$. We begin with a couple of remarks.

The problem is that I don't see where in the proof we use the fact that $\Lambda$ is a groupoid. It seems to me that $\Lambda$ can be any category.
The following is a sketch of the proof as I understand it.
To define the functor $\lambda$ on morphisms, i.e. homotopies of paths, we first define it on paths $\omega$ by subdividing the domain $[0,1]$ of $\omega$ into subintervals small enough that $\omega$ maps into one of the $X_\nu$ on each of the intervals. $\omega$ is thus a product of paths, each of which has a well-defined $\lambda$ value (using the functors $h_\nu$). Taking the product of those values in $\Lambda$ yields a well-defined value for $\lambda(\omega)$.
Next, we need to show that $\lambda$ respects homotopies relative endpoints. We take such a homotopy $H$ from $\omega$ to $\omega'$, say. We observe that $\lambda(\omega) = \lambda(\omega * \gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is the constant path $\gamma(t) = H(1,t)$. Similary, $\lambda(\omega') = \lambda(\delta * \omega')$ where $\delta$ is the constant path $\delta(t) = H(0,t)$. That is, we need to show that going through the homotopy by following its bottom edge, then the right edge is the same as following the left edge, followed by the top, as far as $\lambda$ is concerned. For that, we break up the rectangle into subrectangles on each of which $H$ takes values in one of the $X_\nu$, and by sequence wiggles, i.e. by following each subrectangle along edges from its bottom, lower point to its right, upper point, in two different ways, we get what we want.
What am I missing?

It indeed does not matter whether $\Lambda$ is a groupoid or an ordinary category. To any category $\mathcal{C}$ one can associate the groupoid $\mathrm{core}(\mathcal{C})$, which has the same objects as $\mathcal{C}$, but only isomorphisms as morphisms. This extends to a functor $\mathrm{core}\colon \mathrm{Cat}\to\mathrm{Grpd}$. If $\mathcal{G}$ is a groupoid, then any functor $F\colon \mathcal{G}\to \mathcal{C}$ factors uniquely through $\mathrm{core}(\mathcal{C})$, since $F$ preserves isomorphisms.
In other words, $\mathrm{core}$ is right adjoint to the inclusion $\mathrm{Grpd}\to \mathrm{Cat}$. Since left adjoints preserve colimits, in particular pushouts, it does not matter whether one shows that the diagram in the theorem is a pushout in $\mathrm{Grpd}$ (which is what tom Dieck does) or in $\mathrm{Cat}$.
